# How to properly detect IdentityError type?

Tags: .net, identityserver4

I try to detect the kind of `IdentityError` returned. The `Code` property is a `string` I would expect it to be an enum or at least that there is string const for each code. I can't find any of that.
Right now I detect duplicate email error, this way:

```
if(identityResult.Errors.Any(x => x.Code == "DuplicateEmail"))
```

Is there any way to get rid of that literal?

Answer (score 4):

In *Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll* there is an IdentityErrorDescriber class.

You can use it like this:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

if (identityResult.Errors.Any(x => x.Code == nameof(IdentityErrorDescriber.DuplicateEmail)))
```

---

**Update**

The ErrorDescriber is also part of the UserManager, allowing you to customize the error message.

```
// model.Email is 'someone@somemail.com'.
var identityError = _userManager.ErrorDescriber.DuplicateEmail(model.Email);

if (identityResult.Errors.Any(x => x.Code == identityError.code))
{
    // Description: "Email 'someone@somemail.com' is already taken.
    var message = identityError.Description;

}
```